# Missing assembly reference EF MVC 5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I updated my EF model from the database, and I now have an error...

> CS0246 The type or namespace name '`<tablename>`' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assebmly reference?)

What causes the reference to be lost after an update?

UPDATE:

After reviewing the repository, it seems that the Model.Context.cs has it's entire contents removed (which had the definition to the DbContext class).

But the tables are still broken entities even though the Model.edmx[Diagram1] shows all the tables correctly.

Comment: Where is this type or namespace being used?  Where is it defined?

Comment: It was in the Model.Context.cs. I found that the entire class was stripped of it's contents. It still is giving the error for the tables after replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have this table in your database, this happens when you update the EDMX and one of the tables that were in the EDMX are not in the database.

Comment: None of the tables disappeared, just the namespace broke

Comment: Did you try to remove the table from the EDMX and add again?